# Inserting randomized data into Vertica database using php

Tags: php, database, vertica

My goal is to generate random data (floats, strings, dates, etc) using php and then inserting the data into a database on a `Vertica` server. I don't know what I'm doing very well but I tried to use a for loop to create and insert the data.

```
$RecCount = 10000;
    function generateRandomString($length = 60) {
    return substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
}

for($i = 0; $i < $RecCount; ++$i) 
{
    $a=mt_rand(0,1000000);
    $b=generateRandomString();

    $timestamp = mt_rand(1, time());

    $rd = date('d M Y', $timestamp);
    $rt = date('H:i:s', $timestamp);
    $ts = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 hour') );

    $sql = "INSERT into test values('$i','$a','$b','$rd','$rt','$ts','t')";
    $result = errortrap_odbc($conn, $sql);

    # Insert data into the table with odbc_prepare and odbc_execute
    $values = array($i,$a,$b,$rd,$rt,$ts,'t');
    $statement = odbc_prepare($conn,"INSERT into test values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");


    if(!$result = odbc_execute($statement, $values)) {
        echo "odbc_execute Failed!" . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "Success: odbc_execute." . "\n";
    }
}
```

The script worked as intended and managed to run 10k insert loops in about 5 minutes but I'm wondering if there's some way I can optimize this and make it significantly faster, as my final goal is to compare the insert speeds of the `Vertica` server to a `MySQL` server so I'd like it to be as efficient as possible.

Maybe the for loop is the wrong way to go? I just didn't know how else to do it.

Comment: Consider posting to [codereview.se] - that's the place for working code just needing optimisations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Turn off autocommit if you have it on. (You can always turn it back on later).  Be sure to commit after you finish.

   ```
   # Turn on autocommit before executing insert
   odbc_autocommit ( $conn, false );

   # After all executes are successful, commit the work
   odbc_commit ( $conn );
   ```
2. Also, do not `odbc_prepare` inside your loop. You should be preparing before the loop, it only needs to be done once.

The only other way to make it faster for Vertica would be to use batch execute (not supported as far as I know for php odbc or pdo).  Batch execute would get turned into a much more efficient `COPY` statement. The other alternative is to use `COPY` however you'd have to  jump through hoops probably. If you really have a lot of data then you'd want to. This isn't something you could easily do within PHP. It would involve either executing vsql or creating a file on the cluster.

If you really want to compare Vertica vs. MySQL then this is definitely not playing to Vertica's strengths. Vertica is extremely fast at loading data, but is not fast at executing tons of small queries. What are you testing is how fast is inserting into both databases from PHP. Because there is no batch execute, MySQL is likely to win.

Comment: I'm aware of that. My first goal is to compare the insert speeds and my second goal is to compare loading speed, hopefully there Vertica will outperform MySQL

Comment: @Greip If you can switch to a `COPY` it will likely outperform.  If you use python, you can use `vertica_python` or the new python module that Vertica offers. Both support `COPY` and are pretty easy to use. Otherwise you'll need to use `vsql` or `java`.  The `JDBC` driver will also convert batch `INSERT` into a `COPY`.